# It is possible to use in BigQuery parameters with variables concatenated inside an IN () without the use of EXECUTE

Tags: sql, automation, google-bigquery, parameter-passing

I am trying to parameterize querys in bigquery and make it look clean, since these queries will be transferred to put them into production and the idea is to create a table with the parameters that will be applied to all these queries. Works when the parameter is just a variable and we use a between or is equal, the problem is that I don't know how to apply it with an IN:

- Example of `PARAMETER_TABLE`

```html
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;    
}
</style>
<table >
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">PROCES_NAME</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">FILTER</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">proces 1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">'FILTER1','FILTER2','FILTER3'</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

- What I look for

```
DECLARE @PARAM_FILTER;
DECLARE @QUERY STRING; 
SET PARAM_FILTRO_GENERAL = ( SELECT FILTER FROM PARAMETER_TABLE WHERE PROCES_NAME= 'PROCESO 1');
SELECT * FROM MAIN_TABLE a  ,    unnest(a.trade) as b WHERE YEAR_MONTH = 202008 AND b.trade_activity IN (@PARAM_FILTER)
```

Now I currently have a pseudo solution but I don't see it very compatible using "WITH" closures, because it is important to avoid creating tables and so all these processes have their query with a general format, I hope to explain myself well.

```
DECLARE @PARAM_FILTERSTRING;
DECLARE @QUERY STRING; 
SET PARAM_FILTRO_GENERAL = ( SELECT FILTER FROM `PARAMETER_TABLE` WHERE PROCES_NAME= 'PROCESO 1');
SET QUERY = CONCAT("SELECT cdp_cust_id,b.trade_activity,b.last_transaction_date,value_1 FROM `MAIN_TABLE`  a  ,    unnest(a.trade) as b WHERE YEAR_MONTH = 202008 AND b.trade_activity IN (",PARAM_FILTER,") ");
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QUERY;
```

Answer (score 1):

because of @PARAM_FILTER is of STRING data type - you need to make sure it is wrapped with quotes or apostrophe - you should add them - see the fix at the end of below line

```
SET QUERY = CONCAT("SELECT cdp_cust_id,b.trade_activity,b.last_transaction_date,value_1 FROM `MAIN_TABLE`  a  ,    unnest(a.trade) as b WHERE YEAR_MONTH = 202008 AND b.trade_activity IN ('",PARAM_FILTER,"') ");
```

specifically - change is apostrophes in `('",PARAM_FILTER,"')`

> Update for the first query - based on sample data for PARAMETER_TABLE

Your last line in that first query should look as below

```
SELECT * FROM MAIN_TABLE a, UNNEST(a.trade) as b WHERE YEAR_MONTH = 202008 AND "'" || b.trade_activity ||"'" IN UNNEST(SPLIT(PARAM_FILTER))
```

Comment: Hello Mikhail, thanks for your fast answer, now regarding your comment I understand what you say but the second example already works because the single quotes are already included in the parameter table, what I want is to make the parameter work in the first example without use execute.

Comment: i see - was not clear enough. will check again shortly

Comment: @DanielIglesiasValenzuela - see update  to address your comments. I briefly tested it with example data presented in your question and it did worked

Comment: wow really, can be because im using web ui for bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution, a example of the string that in my case use pipe as separator because some string use comma who is the default, and string without single.

--SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT("AIRLINES, AIR CARRIERS|AIR CANADA",'|'))

```
   DECLARE PARAM_FILTER;
    DECLARE QUERY STRING; 
    SET PARAM_FILTRO_GENERAL = ( SELECT FILTER FROM PARAMETER_TABLE WHERE PROCES_NAME= 'PROCESO 1');
    SELECT * FROM MAIN_TABLE a  ,    unnest(a.trade) as b WHERE YEAR_MONTH = 202008 
AND b.trade_activity IN UNNEST(SPLIT(PARAM_FILTER))
```

Comment: The data sample you use here is different from what is in your original question - that is why here you don't need extra apostrophies around trade_activity

Comment: yes sir, to make this work the parameter table must change whit no apostrophies inside the variable. But the key is the use of this 2 function UNNEST AND SPLIT to make them work on IN clause because its been considering one filter instred of 2 diferent one, thanks mikhail for you support.